# Account merging

Tags: support, user-accounts

The accounts https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/9569/stat-r, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/9583/stat-r should probably be merged because they have been created from the same person, who asked about the merging on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125758/i-was-about-to-merge-my-stackoverflow-account-how-to-protect-my-points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks.  A better way to indicate such situations is to contact the mods directly.  One way simply is to flag any question; you'll get a textbox with space for a few hundred characters to explain what's going on.

In this case, it does *look* like these are the same user, but it's possible they are two different people who happen to have chosen the same moniker.

Comment: Whoops… I didn't notice the unregistered account had posts. I forgot an unregistered account is not allowed to flag posts, and that is the reason the user didn't flag any post. As moderator, I could have also sent a message from the Teachers' Lounge. `:)` Thank you for your reply.